# Laravel $collection->key = "value" doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

The following code doesn't work in Laravel 7.

```
$collection = collect();
$collection->key = "value"
Log::debug($collection) // returns empty array []
```

But this code does.

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->key = "value"
```

If I understand correctly, `Auth::user()` should also return a collection.
Why doesn't the first one work but the second one does?

Using a decoded JSON object also appears to work

```
$object = json_decode($data);
$object->key = "value"
```

It does work if you use `$collection->put('key', 'value')` but I'm curious as to why the first way doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Auth::user() does not return a collection. It returns the current user. Its a single model object.

Comment: How should I initialize the object instead, then? I just want an object with keys and values.

Comment: Create a new model or stdClass - you don't want a collection in this case.

Comment: ```$object = new stdClass();``` gives a fatal error when I use it in Laravel. What should I use instead?

Comment: That's a standard php function - what is the error if you try `$object = new \stdClass();`

Comment: @Watercayman It works, but now I can't convert it to a string. 
```Log::debug(Auth::user())``` will give me a stringified json but 
```$object = new \stdClass(); 
Log::debug($object);``` does not.

Comment: Did you add a value?  Take Log::debug out for a bit, just concentrate on what you're getting.  Just `dd($object)` after adding the value and compare to `dd($user)` to see what the difference is.

Comment: @Watercayman dd appears to work. The values show up as they should in the object. why does ```Log::debug``` work with the other objects but not with my stdClass object? Not having access to the object in the log would make debugging pretty difficult.

Comment: Different output method.  You have what you need to make this work.  The `dd` output will be the same as if you move this to blade.

Comment: @Watercayman dd stops code execution. Is there some way to make some standard object compatible with laravel's Log::debug?

Comment: `dd` dumps the object - `Log::` looks for a string.  `Log::($object->yourNewValue)` will solve this for you.

Comment: @Watercayman ```Log::debug(json_encode($object))``` also works, it turns out. I think the model class has a tostring method that handles this problem automatically, stdclass doesn't. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pull a single value from a collection in the first instance.  You need to add an object to the collection and then attach a value to that object for it to work.

The second example:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->key = "value"
```

works because `$user` is a single object.  It is equivalent to what you might get from a `first()` or `find($id)` directive - single object that will take a value rather than a collection which will not.

You can create your own object and add the key you wish to it:

```
$object = new \stdClass();
$object->value = 'Your Value';
```

Now you can dump to `Log` with the string portion:
    Log::debug($object->value);

Or as you note, `Log` just needs a string, so JSON works too:

```
Log::debug(json_encode($object))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `put()` method instead:

```
$collection->put('key', 'value');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-put

Auth::user() returns a type of Model class